# Fast scroll behavior on earlier android versions

Tags: android, listview, scroll, fastscroll

I'am developing  an application for android spanning from API level 8 to 14. I'am trying to get the same fast scroll behavior of android 4 (see contacts-app) in the earlier versions (fixed stylish scrollbar on the right side). Has anyone an idea how to achieve this?
I tried to find a way to overwrite the fastScroll-Drawable of my `ListView` but without success. Important is, that this is not the normal scrollbar but the fastscroll-action.

[image: image 1]

Answer (score 0):

Did u try adding

```
  android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
```

Comment: This is working for Android-4-Devices with Holo-Theme. The problem is, that `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` results in two different behaviors on Android 4 compared to pre Android-4-Devices. The question is more like: How can I achive the Android-4 FastScroll-behaviour on pre Android-4 devices. (styles, drawables, etc. are no problem, only the behavior of the thumbscroller)